# Kmeans Cluster for each group in pandas dataframe and assign clusters

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, cluster-computing, k-means

I would like to cluster X2 and X3 for group month by using kmeans clustering. I need to cluster combined two variables. Also I would like to assign cluster 0 ,cluster 1 and cluster 2 to "strong","average","weak" according to the mean of each cluster highest means mean strong cluster. Below is my sample data set.

```
df=pd.DataFrame({'month':['1','1','1','1','1','2','2','2','2','2','2','2'],'X1': 
[30,42,25,32,12,10,4,6,5,10,24,21],'X2':[10,76,100,23,65,94,67,24,67,54,87,81],'X3': 
[23,78,95,52,60,76,68,92,34,76,34,12]})
df
```

I need to automate this and since then  I have so many cols I would like to do this on  2 cols (df.loc[:,2:3]) in general. Assigning cluster to each def is

cluster 2="best"

cluster 1="average"

cluster 0="weak"

To find the best cluster find the mean of each column and then sum if it is higest then assign it to "best", lower to average, and lowest to "weak"

Please help thank you

Comment: Can you elaborate on `.Also I would like to assign cluster 0 ,cluster 1 and cluster 2 to "strong","average","weak" according to the mean of each cluster `?

Comment: Yes sir after finding clusters find the mean(df.loc[:,2:3]) of each column of each cluster and sums if it is the highest then call that cluster "best"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### `groupby` and `apply` a clustering function

We can group the dataframe by `month` and cluster the columns `X2` and `X3` using a custom defined clustering function

```
cols = df.columns[2:4]
mapping = {0: 'weak', 1: 'average', 2: 'best'}

def cluster(X):
    k_means = KMeans(n_clusters=3).fit(X)
    return X.groupby(k_means.labels_)\
            .transform('mean').sum(1)\
            .rank(method='dense').sub(1)\
            .astype(int).to_frame()

df['Cluster_id'] = df.groupby('month')[cols].apply(cluster)
df['Cluster_cat'] = df['Cluster_id'].map(mapping)
```

---

```
   month  X1   X2  X3  Cluster_id Cluster_cat
0      1  30   10  23           0        weak
1      1  42   76  78           1     average
2      1  25  100  95           2        best
3      1  32   23  52           0        weak
4      1  12   65  60           1     average
5      2  10   94  76           2        best
6      2   4   67  68           2        best
7      2   6   24  92           1     average
8      2   5   67  34           0        weak
9      2  10   54  76           2        best
10     2  24   87  34           0        weak
11     2  21   81  12           0        weak
```

Comment: Shubham I need to cluster not for each variable but for two variables one cluster Thanks

Comment: Do we need to cluster by `X2` and `X3` combined?

Comment: but still getting X2_cluster and X3_cluster thanks

Comment: Great answer! Concise and effective!

Comment: @melik Can you please edit your question with the expected output?

Comment: @melik If i am understanding correctly you want to find the mean of  `X2` and `X3` per month per cluster then sum the means of `X2` and `X3` and decide the best cluster on the basis of this information?

Comment: Yes exactly find the mean of X2 and X3 per month per cluster then sum the means of X2 and X3 and decide the best cluster

Comment: @melik Edited the answer please check.

Comment: Shubham would you please add also the orginal cluster column that I can check the answer Thanks

Comment: Not sure what you meant by original cluster column. Can you elaborate?

Comment: like cluster_new column with 1,1,1,0,1,2,2,2,.... Thanks

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/231826/discussion-between-shubham-sharma-and-melik).

Comment: Sgubham I noticed that this function does not order according to the sum of mean. It only assign 0 to weak , 1 to average, 2 to best. Is it possible you can check it?